# Sorting array of strings such that substrings of any other string will comes later

Tags: string, algorithm, sorting, optimization

I want to find an algorithm which can sort (or arrange) array of the strings such that if any string (say B) is sub-string of any other string (say ABAC) than that B should come after ABAC.
e.g. :

suppose the string are :

```
abc
bc
zef
abcde
```

then order will be :

```
abcde, 
abc, 
bc 
and zef can come anywhere in the order.
```

Comment: What programming language do you like the code to be in? Also, in the event where, say, string "bc" is a substring of two string, where would you like "bc" to go. For example, there are 3 strings, "abc", "dbc", and "bc". Where would you like "bc" to go in that case?

Comment: "bc" could go anywhere after "abc" and "dbc" but "abc" and "dbc" order doesn't matter.

Comment: @KevinNg any programming language or pseudo code will work as long as i am able to understand how algorithm works like C,C++, python, Java, php etc.

Comment: Build a trie seems to be a good approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort algorithms are based on comparing pairs of values. Often programming languages allow to provide the built-in sort-method with a comparator function, which should take two arguments, and return an integer value indicating their relative order (-1, 0 or 1).

So define the comparator as follows:

```
compare(a, b):
    if a is substring of b then return 1
    if b is substring of a then return -1
    if a < b then return -1
    if a > b then return 1
    return 0
```

This substring-test should first check the length of the two strings to potentially avoid a scan of the strings. Because when `a.length > b.length`, then *a* cannot be a substring of *b*. Or you could also explicitly write:

```
compare(a, b):
    if a.length <= b.length and a is substring of b then return 1
    if a.length >= b.length and b is substring of a then return -1
    if a < b then return -1
    if a > b then return 1
    return 0
```

If the target programming language does not offer this possibility, then you should write your own sorting function (like QuickSort), and make sure it can use such a comparator, so that (starting from a standard implementation) you would replace:

```
 if a < b
```

with:

```
 if compare(a, b) < 0
```

...etc.

### Transitivity of the relationship

Let's assume for a moment that the relationship that is encoded in the compare function is not transitive, so that we could find three strings a, b and c for which:

- compare(a, b) < 0
- compare(b, c) < 0
- but also: compare(c, a) <= 0

First, note what this says about the lengths of the three strings:

- compare(a, b) < 0 implies that a.length >= b.length
- compare(b, c) < 0 implies that b.length >= c.length
- compare(c, a) <= 0 implies that c.length >= a.length

From the first two we conclude that a.length >= c.length, and combining that with the third, we can conclude all three strings have the same length.

So now we have:

- compare(a, b) < 0 implies that  a is alphabetically ordered before b
- compare(b, c) < 0 implies that b is alphabetically ordered before c
- compare(c, a) <= 0 implies that c is alphabetically ordered before a, or is equal to a.

This leads to a contradiction. And so we must conclude that the relationship is transitive.

Comment: I don't think this will work as here you are using comparison sort which uses the transitive property of comparison which your comparative function doesn't follow.;

Comment: e.g.  
  if three strings are 
  A : "abc" ,
  B : "bc" ,
  C : "bcef" 
  
  then from you comparison function :
  
  compare(A,B) < 0
  compare(B,C) = 0
  
  then sorting algorithm makes a assumption that
  
  compare(A,C) < 0 which clearly isn't true.

Comment: @Sagar, you may have a point, but I don't see it in your example. First of all, I had the return value reversed putting substrings first, which I have corrected now, so they come last. But so far I see no problem in the conclusion that the algorithm makes from earlier comparisons. compare(A, C) is really not determined by the OP's conditions: they could be ordered either way, since neither is a substring of the other. Do you have another counter example?

Comment: See the proof of transitivity I added to my answer.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. i am also not able to find any counterexample so i have marked this as the solution.

Comment: Your transitivity proof only works if `a<b` means that `a` is longer than `b`. Lexicographic comparison does not make that guarantee, but of course you can use a comparison function which does make that guarantee since the fallback comparison is not relevant as long as it is consistent and transitive. But that leads to the idea of *only* comparing the lengths; that's sufficient to ensure that substrings will come after their superstrings without ever having to check for substring containment, or even lexicographic ordering. Just comparing lengths seems a lot cheaper.